# How to discard colorbar shadow in contour ploting in mathematica

Tags: plotting, legending

I am plotting a contour plot in *Mathematica* with `Showlegend` command, but trouble is that I am getting a black shadow with colorlegend which I want to remove.

```
ShowLegend[
    ContourPlot[SS[10^-3 t, λo xx], {t, 0, 0.2}, {xx, -4 λo, 4 λo}, 
    ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"], Ticks -> {{0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2}, 
    {-4 λo, -2 λo, 0, 2 λo, 4 λo}} {ColorData ["Rainbow"][1 - #1] &, 10, " 1", "-1", 
    LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}}, ContourLabels -> False, 
    Contours -> 20, LegendShadow -> None, LegendBorderSpace -> 0, 
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, False}}, Axes -> True, 
    FrameLabel -> {Style[Time[ms], 12], Style[x, 12]}, 
    AspectRatio -> 0.5, LabelStyle -> Bold]
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code and a picture of the result you obtain from it, so we can more easily help you.

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: The code you posted is not self-contained. It can not be evaluated without additional information. Such as the definition of `SS`. Also, the `PlotLegends` package is obsolete and doesn't work well with recent version of _Mathematica_. What version are you running?

Comment: Sorry, i forget to defined SS here, but in my program it is defined over there. I am using mathematica8. Problem is following. Colorlegend is not picking the color values from contour plot rather it is picking up the values which i defined in program eg. "1", "-1". Which make colarlegend inconsistent with contourplot.

Answer (score 6):

Use the option

```
LegendShadow -> None
```

From [`Plot Legends` documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/PlotLegends/ref/LegendShadow.html)

> `LegendShadow` 
>   is an option for `Legend` that specifies the shadowing drawn around the legend.

Comment: this command is not working.

Comment: Have you tried the examples in the documentation? I've tested once more to be sure and it worked as expected! It is supposed to be used as in `ShowLegend[ (*Plot code*), { (*Legend code*) , LegendShadow -> None }]` (note the `{}`)

Comment: Ya now it seem to be working, One more problem is coming, for contour plot particular color has a fix value but we can change the Colorlegend index "1", "-1" aw we wish. so how contour plot colorvariation will match with colorbar index.

Comment: That is a different question altogether, and I don't think there is a straightforward way to do so with the old `PlotLegends`! You should try the new `PlotLegends` option (v9 upwards, I think)